# Why the screen resolution ratio is not the same as screen dimension ratio?

Tags: android, android-camera, resolution, screen-resolution

I'm developing an Android application to take pictures and notice that the screen dimension ratio (480/800=0.6 for my HTC Desire X) is not the same as the picture resolution (1552/2592=0.5987) when I take picture by the default Camera application.The application has a fullscreen preview.

Does anyone know why there is this tiny difference ? And how does the default application handle this variance ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why *would* the camera necessarily have the same ratio as the screen?!

Comment: There are probably many possible picture resolutions that can be taken by the camera, using the `Camera` API. None have to have an aspect ratio that matches the screen's aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

When you are initializing the camera, you can set a number of different parameters. The relevant ones to this question are preview size and picture size. If you are using the standard method of taking pictures (the [`takePicture()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture(android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback)) method), the *picture* size will be set using [`setPictureSize()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPictureSize(int,%20int)) method for the camera parameters.

The preview size (you mentioned that you have fullscreen preview) is set independently of the picture size.

To set preview size, look at the [supported preview sizes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes()), and then [set the preview size](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewSize(int,%20int)).
To set the picture size, look at the [supported picture sizes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPictureSizes()), and then [set the picture size](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPictureSize(int,%20int)).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I actually iterate over all the preview sizes and picture sizes and pick the couple having the "nearest" ratio. The problem above rather comes  from the screen ratio (dimension) which is not the same as the preview and picture ratio.

Comment: Something is then a little unclear in your question. So, when you display the picture after taking it, it is stretched? Since your image is a bit "skinnier" than your screen at equal heights, i would scale the picture preview just slightly so the aspect ratios are equal and with widths are equal. This will mean cropping a little bit off the top and bottom in fullscreen image preview.

Comment: Displaying the picture after is ok as it doesn't take the fullscreen. Maybe I can set the preview size to have the same ratio as the screen one but I still wonder about the "trick" used by the default camera app to hide the ratio difference :).

Comment: it is actual with new camera2 api?